# Resize UIScrollView with setcontentsize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to resize UIScrollView inside a UICOllectionViewCell but it doesn't resize it.

```
-(int)resizeScrollView:(int)height{

    NSLog(@"Before Scroll height %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    float currentHeight=self.scrollView.frame.size.height+height+200;
    NSLog(@"height %f",currentHeight);
    CGSize size=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width ,
                           currentHeight + 10 );
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:size];    
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    NSLog(@"After Scroll height %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    return currentHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `contentSize` adjusts the amount of logical space that the scroll view scrolls over.  You need to set the `frame` or the `bounds` to adjust the size of the scrollview in its parent view.

```
CGRect scrollFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
scrollFrame.size.height += height + 210;
self.scrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

Comment: what is the context in which you are calling `-resizeScrollView`?

Comment: yes it is resizescrollview. i end up re-create the frames and add it to scrollview.